# Virt-manager Permission Denied when accessing NFS pool

Tags: nfs, kvm, qemu

I'm currently having this error
[image]

when I'm trying to install a Virtual Machine on my NFS share. i've added my NFS share (coming from FreeNAS) to a Storage Pool on the virt-manager [image]

Another issue is that I can't seem to read my ISO files from another NFS share either aswell.
Hopefully you can solve this issue.

I've tried the following:

- qemu.conf - uncomment the user to force root user
- mapall user to root in my freenas share (all users get the root permission)

Answer (score 5):

The problem most probable is not related to Freenas nfs rights but to the selinux (or apparmor if you use Ubuntu) config of the host.

According to the libvirt documentation http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#securityselinux

> SELinux basic confinement  The basic SELinux protection for QEMU
>   virtual machines is intended to protect the host OS from a compromised
>   virtual machine process. There is no protection between guests.
>
> In the basic model, all QEMU virtual machines run under the confined
>   domain root:system_r:qemu_t. It is required that any disk image
>   assigned to a QEMU virtual machine is labelled with
>   system_u:object_r:virt_image_t. In a default deployment, package
>   vendors/distributor will typically ensure that the directory
>   /var/lib/libvirt/images has this label, such that any disk images
>   created in this directory will automatically inherit the correct
>   labelling. If attempting to use disk images in another location, the
>   user/administrator must ensure the directory has be given this
>   requisite label. Likewise physical block devices must be labelled
>   system_u:object_r:virt_image_t.
>
> Not all filesystems allow for labelling of individual files. In
>   particular NFS, VFat and NTFS have no support for labelling. In these
>   cases administrators must use the 'context' option when mounting the
>   filesystem to set the default label to system_u:object_r:virt_image_t.
>   In the case of NFS, there is an alternative option, of enabling the
>   virt_use_nfs SELinux boolean.

To check if the right labels are there do an `ls -Z` on the directory where you store the VM images.

To enable nfs access to the vm's you need to use:

`setsebool virt_use_nfs on`