# How to use QEMU/KVM virtual machine disk image on SMB/CIFS network share: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm, qemu, libvirt

#### Environment

- SMB network share `temp` is mounted as follows, logged-in user `dave`:

  ```
  sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,uid=dave,gid=dave //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
  ```
- Effective `temp` mount folder permissions:

  ```
  $ ls -al /media/nas/
  drwxr-xr-x 2 dave dave    0 Nov 30 10:14 temp/
  ```
- libvirtd runs as root:

  ```
  $ ps aux | grep libvirt 
  root         902  0.0  0.2 1559756 42420 ?       Ssl  Nov29   0:06 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
  ```
- [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/) (my used libvirt frontend) runs with user `dave` permission:
- vanilla, untouched QEMU config
- User `dave` already has been added to groups `libvirt` and `kvm` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) (OS is Ubuntu 20.04):

  ```
  sudo adduser `id -un` libvirt
  sudo adduser `id -un` kvm
  ```
- libvirt URI is `qemu:///system`

#### Problem

I can write/read as `dave` to `temp` directly from the shell or Files application. The share owner is set to `uid=dave,gid=dave`, which is the user belonging to `kvm` and `libvirt`. Running VMs with *local* `.qcow2` disk image path is no problem. In virt-manager, I am able to define `/media/nas/temp` as storage pool (the directory containing the images).

But as soon as I want to place or create this disk image file in `/media/nas/temp`, there is a "Permission denied" error triggered. As far as I know, virtual machines with `qemu:///system` are instantiated and run as `root`. This should not affect the configured network share owner in any way. I event tried `sudo su` and checked, that I am able to write to `/media/nas/temp` as root.

Another way to trigger the error directly (copied from virt-manager output) is:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,compat=1.1,lazy_refcounts /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04 20971520K
```

#### Question

I really would like to understand the permission issue and how to fix it. What is the problem here?

#### Error message in detail

Trying to create a new `.qcow2` disk images triggers:

> Error creating vol: Couldn't create storage volume 'ubuntu20.04': 'internal error: Child process (/usr/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,compat=1.1,lazy_refcounts /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04 20971520K) unexpected exit status 1: qemu-img: /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04: Could not write qcow2 header: Permission denied
> '
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/storage.py", line 682, in install
> vol = self.pool.createXML(xml, createflags)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3535, in createXML
> if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virStorageVolCreateXML() failed', pool=self)
> libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Child process (/usr/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,compat=1.1,lazy_refcounts /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04 20971520K) unexpected exit status 1: qemu-img: /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04: Could not write qcow2 header: Permission denied
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
> callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvol.py", line 339, in _async_vol_create
> vol.install(meter=meter)
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/storage.py", line 691, in install
> raise RuntimeError("Couldn't create storage volume "
> RuntimeError: Couldn't create storage volume 'ubuntu20.04': 'internal error: Child process (/usr/bin/qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata,compat=1.1,lazy_refcounts /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04 20971520K) unexpected exit status 1: qemu-img: /media/nas/temp/ubuntu20.04: Could not write qcow2 header: Permission denied
> '

#### Update: What I further tried

- searched for other error types via `journalctl -xf` (nothing else than above message)
- searched for denied operations via `cat /var/log/syslog | grep DENIED | grep libvirt` (nothing)
- Experimentally disabled AppArmor via `systemctl stop apparmor` - no effect
- created an image successfully in other local folders than `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`

#### Update 2: Using `nobrl` mount option

If I use the `nobrl` mount option ([thanks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622194/how-to-use-qemu-kvm-virtual-machine-disk-image-on-smb-cifs-network-share-permis#comment1163997_622194) [to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622254/444085) rudib) with owner still `uid=dave,gid=dave` as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,uid=dave,gid=dave,nobrl //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
```

, the storage volume can be successfully created (step 4/5 in virt-manager wizard). Though in step 5/5, I now get another "Permission denied" error:

> Unable to complete install: 'internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-12-01T06:03:01.710704Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-2-storage","backing":null}: Could not reopen file: Permission denied'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
> callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2089, in _do_async_install
> guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 542, in start_install
> domain = self._create_guest(
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 491, in _create_guest
> domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4034, in createXML
> if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
> libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-12-01T06:03:01.710704Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-2-storage","backing":null}: Could not reopen file: Permission denied

Not specifying `uid` and `gid` leads to following permissions:

```
$ ll /media/nas/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root     0 Dez  1 07:01 temp/
```

, the error being the same as before.

Comment: I think this is a [selinux issue](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/sect-virtualization-security_for_virtualization-selinux_and_virtualization). I'm not sure if you can use selinux with smb, but I think I've had the same error before.

Comment: I think you can set `context="virt_image_t"` in the mount options. That might work (but will apply for the whole mount; I guess you'd need a dedicated mount for vm images...).

Comment: Also `qemu:///system` does not run as your user, you might have to change the share user to `root` (as in `/var/lib/libvirt/images`, which is the default directory for the `system` images)

Comment: @rudib thanks for the hints, appreciate it. As far as I know, Ubuntu comes with AppArmor installed (at least I don't have SELinux installed on this machine). And I could not find any specifics AppArmor errors with `journalctl -xf`, when repeating above steps. I also tried `-o username=dave,vers=3.11,uid=root,gid=root,context="virt_image_t" //nas/temp /media/nas/temp`, `context="virt_image_t"` seems to be ignored according to `mount -l` and unfortunately does not work (also with `uid=dave,gid=dave`). Hm, this seems to be more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the apparmor. In selinux, it seems to actually be [just a flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249937/virt-manager-permission-denied-when-accessing-nfs-pool). I'm not sure about apparmor. You might have to update the profile - but if there are no errors... Have you checked `dmesg` too? Or something like `audit.log`?

Comment: No, I only could find the permission denied error as shown above in the logs. It seems, it is not AppArmor's fault - I experimentally disabled it via `systemctl stop apparmor`, with same result. Also nothing  about `DENIED` operations of libvirt via `cat /var/log/syslog | grep DENIED | grep libvirt`.

Comment: Btw: I also can create images in other local folders, not just `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`. There  must be something different, when on the mounted network path.

Comment: Have you tried `uid=qemu,gid=root` and `uid=root,gid=root` as mount options yet? Other ideas: do you have enough free space on the server? you could try enabling [cifs debugging](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting) maybe there's a hint to be found there. When I find the time, I'll see if I can get it working on my selinux setup.

Comment: I think I've unraveled the mystery: try using the `nobrl` mount option: `mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,nobrl //nas/temp /media/nas/temp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** An active volume that is mounted remotely can cause some problems and add latency

It seems that qemu-img can't deal with the byte range locks that are a default mount option for `cifs`. The flag `nobrl` should fix that:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,nobrl,uid=libvirt-qemu //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
```

During image creation with `qemu:///system` `uid=libvirt-qemu` doesn't seem to be required as `virt-manager` seems to run `qemu-img create` as root. However, as `qemu:///system` machines are started under the qemu user (`libvirt-qemu` [Ubuntu, Debian] or `qemu` [Fedora]), you will get another permission denied error when the share is just mounted as root.

> ```
> nobrl
> Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is
> necessary for certain applications that break with cifs style
> mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support
> requesting advisory byte range locks).
> ```

When you are using `selinux`, you might need to set the sebool `virt_use_samba`.

Comment: Awesome! `nobrl` definitely helped to clear up the first permission error. For the last  install step in virt-manager I got a second one - urgh. Fortunately, your other comment helped here as well -  for me, `uid=libvirt-qemu` has been mandatory to successfully run the VM. The complete command: `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,nobrl,uid=libvirt-qemu,gid=root //nas/temp /media/nas/temp`. Can you add that to the answer as well? Thank you so much!

Comment: PS: I cannot up-vote the answer yet, as not enough reputation. Do me a favor and remind me, should I have a bit more - you, sir, deserve a bounty :-)

Comment: Glad it worked! Not to worry, I'm not doing it for the points - I don't mind them either though ;).

Comment: Somebody else had written as comment, that `libvirtd` runs as `root`, but actually starts VMs as `libvirt-qemu` user. For the local system it can change the user dynamically, but for the mount point, it doesn't seem to work, as this is determined/fixed by `uid`, `gid`. I am not sure, why the comment has been deleted, as this was very helpful information (hope I have remembered it correctly). This at least explains, why `libvirt-qemu` is needed (no custom user created by me, but by libvirt installation).

Comment: @A_blop yes, that is correct - but this user can be named differently (usually dictated by the default setup of your distro). E.g.: on fedora it's just `qemu`. I'm a bit curious: did you get an error when you didn't specify `uid` & `gid`? Because I didn't (but I didn't try interacting with the volume in the vm)

Comment: Yes, setting `uid` to `libvirt-qemu` has been absolutely necessary for me (not sure about/didn't play with `gid` though). If I leave out `uid`, there is a second "permission denied" error - see  question update 2 for the message. Do you want to add this info as well concerning `libvirtd` being under `root` permission, running VMs as `libvirt-qemu` and that this user name may vary dependent on distribution (for Ubuntu, it is `libvirt-qemu`)? I find all this hints to be super useful, yet you can find hardly anything about it on  the net (or google failed me :).

Comment: It might have worked for me because I was running `qemu-img create` as root. Ah yes, I get an error too - permission denied. But not on the image creation (probably because virt-manager can run commands as root), but when starting the vm (which is under the `qemu` user).

Comment: Then everything starts to make sense again! I guess, the error I get is also in the course of the VM starting (even if the installation wizard is still shown), as virt-manager starts the VM immediately if everything is configured fine.